# Buttons on “Debug Assertion Failed" popup cannot be clicked?

Tags: c++, qt, debugging

I'm working on develop a Qt GUI application.
This time I got a "Debug Assertion Failed" popup, but the buttons(Abort/Retry/Ignore) on this popup is un-clickable. In other words this popup is stucked. Mainwindow of this application is also stucked.
Has anyone encountered this situation? How can I solve it?

Popup Screenshot:
[image]

Environment:
OS: Win10 64bit
IDE: VS2010
Qt Version: Qt4.8.0

Comment: Can you post some code that may have your error?

Comment: @bogdyname Do you mean code cause this Debug Assertion or code cause popup unclickable?